# IO.fileinfo Class usage in vb.net 2010

Tags: vb.net, timer, vb.net-2010, system.io.fileinfo

I am coding to watch a XYZ folder on the timer tick interval 30,000. If the XYZ folder have the filecount+1 then I want to copy a new file to process.

I can code the rest but stuck at:

> Error 1 'filesindir' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.".

I want to initialize the Filesindir and filesinfo only once. Not on every Tick but have to move/copy new file every time.

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick

    Dim processedfiles = My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles(destfolderpath, "*.ps")


    If processedfiles.Count = (pfiles + 1) Then

        If flag = False Then

            Dim foldertosearch As New IO.DirectoryInfo(folderpath)
            Dim filesindir As IO.FileInfo() = foldertosearch.GetFiles("*.txt")
            Dim filesinfo As IO.FileInfo

        End If

        For Each filesinfo In filesindir




        Next
    End If

    pfiles = processedfiles.Count
End Sub
```

Comment: If you `Dim` the variables inside the If/Then clause, they are out of scope outside that clause. You need to declare them outside the If, or move the `For Each` loop inside the If.

Comment: consider the `System.IO.FileSystemWatcher`  which seems to be what you are recreating

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand [how Scope works in VB.Net](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t0wsc67.aspx).

If you declare a variable in a block, e.g.

```
If Not flag Then
    Dim filesindir As IO.FileInfo() = foldertosearch.GetFiles("*.txt")
End If
```

That `filesindir` variable is scoped to the `If` block. The variable will be inaccessible outside the block.